# Asp.net Core Mvc DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I want to understand how it works 
if I have interface

```
public interface IProductRepository
{
    IQueryable<Product> Products { get; }
}
```

and then I have a class that implements this interface

```
public class EFProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
    public EFProductRepository(ApplicationDBContext ctx)
    {
        context = ctx;
    }
    private ApplicationDBContext context;

    public IQueryable<Product> Products => context.Products;
}
```

and the ApplicationDbContext Class is

```
public class ApplicationDBContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDBContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDBContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

}
```

the ConfigurationServices method is

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:SportStoreProducts:Connectionstring"]);
    });
    services.AddTransient<IProductRepository, EFProductRepository>();
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

after searching about how it works I found that when using `services.AddTransient<IProductRepository, EFProductRepository>();` The components in the application that use the `IProductRepository` interface,  will receive an `EFProductRepository` object when they are created .
but what I want to understand when an object of `EFProductRepository` class is created via this service, the constructor of `EFProductRepository` needs an object of `ApplicationDBContext` class the what technique is used in this case?

Comment: Assuming if by "what technique" you mean "what is the service lifetime of the ApplicationDbContext", though re-reading your question I'm not 100% what you're asking.

Comment: The *technique* is called Dependency Injection.  It's DI all the way through.  The `IServiceProvider` will manage instantiation of all constructor dependencies upon request.